# What is the zmq underlying transport on linux?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

When ZeroMQ is used with *`inproc://`* or *`ipc://`* transport on linux, what exactly is the underlying implementation or operating system construct does it use ? Is it Unix Domain Sockets ? or (named) pipes ? anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

The *`inproc://`* Transport-class, where both Access-Points of the Scalable Formal Communication Pattern archetype are within the same process (address-space), there is no "underlying" transport needed at all. It uses just a zero-copy (pointer-based) memory-address pointing, instead of any byte-moving. This is why this Transport-class (if no other is used) does not even require having a `Context()`-instance (no engine, no high-level queuing buffers, we can imagine it to work just by passing pointers to a new message to the opposite side)

The *`ipc`* Transport-class uses UNIX domain sockets ( that is why it cannot be used on O/S-es, that do not provide UNIX domain sockets. Some bindings yet may circumvent this fact by emulating TCP-based proxy-transport and shuffle the "outer" *`ipc:`*-declared Transport-class services "under the hood" by such a proxy-transport locally available inside such O/S, if all of the counterparties "externally"-claimed to be using *`ipc:`* Transport-class do communicate using this same emulated-service trick )